# how do i pass EntityManager to @PostUpdate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, pass-by-reference, entitymanager

I want to save history of changes, so in @PostUpdate i want to create new instance of another entity and save it, how do i pass EntityManager to that method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get an instance of EntityManager just by retrieving it from the context as you would on any other:

1) Through injection in your class:

```
@PersistenceContext EntityManager em; // injected in your class
```

2) Using EntityManagerFactory:

```
EntityManager em = EntityManagerFactory.getEntityManager();
```

Comment: mmmmmm.... weird. it works for me. what's your JPA implementation? Hibernate? What's your container? JBoss? Tomcat? Weblogic?

Comment: @PersistenceContext annotation works standard only in a EJB server.